# ORA-30657 when creating an interval (or auto list) external partition table

Tags: oracle, partitioning, database-partitioning, oracle-autonomous-db

When trying to create an Interval (or auto list) external partitioned table with DBMS_CLOUD, I am getting ORA-30657: operation not supported on external organized table.

What am I missing?

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_EXTERNAL_PART_TABLE(
  3        table_name =>'PETX',
  4        credential_name =>'MY_CRED',
  5        format => json_object('delimiter' value '#'),
  6        column_list => 'deptno number,dname char(14),loc char(13)',
  7      partitioning_clause => 'partition by range (deptno) interval (15)
  8      (
  9        partition xp1 values less than (15) location(''https://swiftobjectstorage.XXXX/xp1_15.txt'') ,
 10        partition xp2 values less than (30) location (''https://swiftobjectstorage.XXXX/xp2_30.txt'')
 11      )'
 12    );
 13     END;
 14  /

Error starting at line : 5 in command -
BEGIN
   DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_EXTERNAL_PART_TABLE(
      table_name =>'PETX',
      credential_name =>'MY_CRED',
      format => json_object('delimiter' value '#'),
      column_list => 'deptno number,dname char(14),loc char(13)',
    partitioning_clause => 'partition by range (deptno) interval (15)
    (
      partition xp1 values less than (15) location(''https://swiftobjectstorage.XXXX/xp1_15.txt'') ,
      partition xp2 values less than (30) location (''https://swiftobjectstorage.XXXX/xp2_30.txt'')
    )'
  );
   END;
Error report -
ORA-20000: ORA-30657: operation not supported on external organized table
ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 1289
ORA-06512: at "C##CLOUD$SERVICE.DBMS_CLOUD", line 4115
```

Answer (score 0):

Interval and auto-list partitioning is functionality that creates new partitions as-needed, based on new data inserted into the database where the partition key(s) of the new data do not map to any existing partition. With external tables the database does not control the data (or insertion of it), thus the concept of auto-generation of a partition at insertion is not applying to external tables.

Adding a new partition to a partitioned external table is equivalent to having new data files that the table has to point at. You have to tell the database about this, which you are doing by adding a new partition to a table (manually or programmatically).

Short example of how to make the above-example work and how to add a new partition (pointing to additional data files):

```
SQL> 
SQL> BEGIN
  2     DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_EXTERNAL_PART_TABLE(
  3        table_name =>'PETX',
  4        credential_name =>'MY_CRED',
  5        format => json_object('delimiter' value '#'),
  6        column_list => 'deptno number,dname char(14),loc char(13)',
  7      partitioning_clause => 'partition by range (deptno)
  8      (
  9        partition xp1 values less than (15) location(''https://swiftobjectstorage.XXXX/xp1_15.txt'') ,
 10        partition xp2 values less than (30) location (''https://swiftobjectstorage.XXXX/xp2_30.txt'')
 11      )'
 12    );
 13     END;
 14  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> alter table petx add partition xp3 values less than (50) location ('https://swiftobjectstorage.XXXX/xp3_45.txt');

Table PETX altered.

SQL> select count(*) from petx partition (xp3);

  COUNT(*)
----------
  49999999
```

PS: The exact same behavior applies to standard Oracle Database.